# onclick functionality not working only in this div

Tags: html, css, onclick, cordova

I have implemented many onclick functionality. But it is not functioning here alone.

**My HTML**

```
<body style="background-color:#333333;">
<div id="wrapper_other" class="wrapper_other">

<div id="header" class="header">
    <div id="header_title" class="header_title"></div>
    <div id="home" class="home"><img src="img/home.png" onClick="home()"/></div>
</div>
```

**My CSS**

```
.wrapper_other
{
     width:auto; margin:0auto;  overflow: hidden;
}

.header
{
    float:left; height:44px; line-height:44px; margin:0%; width:100%; 
}
.header_title
{
    height:100%; min-height:100%; font-size:22px; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; width:100%; 
}
```

**Myfunction**

```
function home()
{
    window.location.href="index.html";
}
```

**EDIT**

My file structure

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function test()
        {
            window.location.href="index.html";
        }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body style="background-color:#333333;">
 <div id="wrapper_other" class="wrapper_other">
<div id="header" class="header">
    <div id="header_title" class="header_title"></div>
    <div id="home" class="home"><img src="img/home.png"  onClick="info()"/>               </div>
</div>
<div id="images" class="images"><img  name="slide" src="img/banner1.png" width=100% />
    <div id="element_name_image" class="element_name_image"></div>
</div>

<div id="parameters" style="background-image:url(img/icons_bg.png);" class="parameters">
    <div id="abc" class="abc"></div>
    <div id="def" class="def"></div>
    <div id="ghi" class="ghi"></div>
    <div id="jkl" class="jkl"></div>
</div>

 <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
<div id="scroller" class="scroller">    
    <ul>
    <div id="description"  class="description">
        <div id="title"  class="title">
          <h1><strong><ul class="scroller ul"><li></li></ul></strong></h1>
            </div>

            <div id="desc" class="desc">
                <p><ulclass="scroller ul"><li></li></ul></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Please,help me identify my mistake.

Comment: Does your console output any error?

Comment: Provide a fiddle link with your code and images.

Comment: No,when I click,it gets highlighted...no activity in the console.Instead I can add same code functioning well in the other page.

Comment: put an alert inside. Does it work?

Comment: Do you maybe have two elements on this page with same id(home)?

Comment: @nevermind,noI don't have

Comment: @Sergio, It does not go to the function...only the it will process the alert...

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestions.Can I have any other solutions. Please...Please

Comment: Is home() defined after html is created? can home be renamed to homefn to avoid double name with id?

Comment: yes...my file structure..`<htm><head><script>` tried out renaming the function..it was of no use `</script></head><body>--</body><html>`

Comment: please find the edited version..if that could help you out to help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="home" class="home"><img src="img/home.png" onClick='window.location.href="index.html";'/></div>
```

Why don't you use the location.href inside the onClick()?

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestions--This did not help me.upvoted for your answer.Can I have any other solutions. Please...Please

Comment: please find the edited version..if that could help you out to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have used "home" in id attribute and function name. When you use home() onclick, you might have faced not a function exception as Browser refer HTMLDivElement (due to an id attribute). Change the value in id attribute or function name and check

Comment: M.G.Manikandan, no  change

Comment: @user Did you renamed the function name ? What is the error are you getting ?

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestions--upvoted for your answer.Can I have any other solutions. Please...Please

Comment: please find the edited version..if that could help you out to help me.

Answer (score 1):

What is your error? Its working fine see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xNAVh/1/)

```
<div id="wrapper_other" class="wrapper_other">
    <div id="header" class="header">
        <div id="header_title" class="header_title"></div>
        <div id="home" class="home"><img src="img/home.png" onClick="test();"/>   </div>
    </div>
</div>

function test()
{
    window.location.href="index.html";
}
```

**EDIT**
Found your problem
1) Function not defined (test should changed to ->info)
2) onclick (C was capital)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function info()
        {
            window.location.href="index.html";
        }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper_other" class="wrapper_other">
<div id="header" class="header">
    <div id="header_title" class="header_title"></div>
    <div id="home" class="home"><img src="img/home.png" alt="clickme"  onclick="info()"/>               </div>
</div>
<div id="images" class="images"><img  name="slide" src="img/banner1.png" width=100% />
    <div id="element_name_image" class="element_name_image"></div>
</div>

<div id="parameters" style="background-image:url(img/icons_bg.png);" class="parameters">
    <div id="abc" class="abc"></div>
    <div id="def" class="def"></div>
    <div id="ghi" class="ghi"></div>
    <div id="jkl" class="jkl"></div>
</div>

 <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
<div id="scroller" class="scroller">    
    <ul>
    <div id="description"  class="description">
        <div id="title"  class="title">
          <h1><strong><ul class="scroller ul"><li></li></ul></strong></h1>
            </div>

            <div id="desc" class="desc">
                <p><ulclass="scroller ul"><li></li></ul></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestions--upvoted for your answer.Can I have any other solutions. Please...Please

Comment: @user its working fine function any way check with console as whether your getting the message by give the code like following funciton test()
{console.log('Entered');
    window.location.href="index.html";
}

Comment: yes, I had seen your fiddle...but not functioning in mine :-(

Comment: please find the edited version..if that could help you out to help me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31870/discussion-between-thirumalai-murugan-and-user)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the HTML for script.

```
<script type="text/javscript">
function home()
{
    window.location.href="index.html";
}
</script>
```

Now, place the code either the following:

1. inside the `<head>` tag or
2. above the `</body>` tag

Though placing above the ending `<body>` tag is highly recommended.

## Update

Given the directory structure is like this:

```
- index.html
- script.js <- assuming the function is in there
```

Here's the line of code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Then place the code either the following:

1. inside the `<head>` tag or
2. above the `</body>` tag

Comment: yeah I understand your solution,But I want to know,...why is it not accessing in the script file..

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestions--upvoted for your answer.Can I have any other solutions. Please...Please

Comment: please find the edited version..if that could help you out to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong here I can find is 
   1- U have used **home** in as id attribute of div and function name.

```
 <div id="home" class="home"> <img src="img/home.png" onClick="home()"/> </div>
```

2- Try to write **onclick** all in small and put [;] after function call
   show write it like onclick="home();" there will be no error!
 All browser accept it. 
 Try to debug using Chrome console or Internet Explorer(after un-checking - disable script debugging and disable all script debugging).

**Here is Solution:**

HTML CODE with Java Script: **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="yourcss.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function navigator() {
        alert("Test is called!");
            window.location.href = "justchill.html";

    }
    </script>
   </head>
 <body style="background-color: lightyellow">
    <div id="wrapper_other" class="wrapper_other">
        <div id="header" class="header">
            <div id="header_title" class="header_title">
                <img src="Dream_home6.jpg"
                    alt="welcome" onclick="navigator();" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested and verified on Chrome and Mozila Firefox.

Hope it will help.

Comment: My question is the same code is working in the other page not in this page.... Why?..your second point, I have tried it...no use.. **I am checking it in a device**

Comment: @user what is your error, where is your code working? and where its not working

Comment: I don't get any error in my console.On clicking the image.It does not go to the function

Comment: please find the edited version..if that could help you out to help me.

Comment: @user If something is working in one page then it should work in second one too. In your edited version of tags are very jumbled, its hard to find. I have put a very simple code to test just follow that. Remove <b>charset<b/>. Just keep your function name unique, that's all.